# How to make a double click editable table in AngularJS way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Without DOM manipulation, how to make an editable table cell with double click?

I am trying to make it there http://jsfiddle.net/bobintornado/F7K63/35/?

my controller code is below

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        name: "item #1",
        editing: 'readonly'
    }, {
        name: "item #2",
        editing: 'readonly'
    }, {
        name: "item #3",
        editing: 'readonly'
    }];

    $scope.editItem = function (item) {
        item.editing = '';
    };

    $scope.doneEditing = function () {
        //dong some background ajax calling for persistence...
    };
}
```

However I am facing questions to make input element readonly and "submit" the input (on enter pressed event fire up the ajax call to consume some Restful service for updating backend server)

Many thank if anyone could share their wisdom!

PS: I think the editable table of data browser in Parse.com is the best demonstration I can get but I have no clues regarding how to implement it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davekr/F7K63/43/). Is this how you want to do it?

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
        <span ng-hide="item.editing" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">{{item.name}}</span>
        <input ng-show="item.editing" ng-model="item.name" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" autofocus />
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.items = [{name: "item #1", editing: false}, 
                {name: "item #2", editing: false}, 
                {name: "item #3", editing: false}];

$scope.editItem = function (item) {
    item.editing = true;
}

$scope.doneEditing = function (item) {
    item.editing = false;
    //dong some background ajax calling for persistence...
};
```

However you should probably create a directive containing the editable row. And implement the autofocus there, when you dblclick on an item.

Comment: This brilliant! I am struggling to use a single input element to achieve this but it seems harmless to add another span there. I think in future I shall implement a directive like td-editable for fast replicate.

Comment: this implementation is really good, the only problem is that when you edit the field and delete all characters, there is no way to edit it back :/

Comment: @AlejandroLozdziejski put the doubleclick listener on the `td` or `tr` and in even if you have an empty value, you can still edit it

Answer (score 4):

I don't like too much the duplicated-element solution so I tried another way and it's working perfectly without complicating the model.

This is my first contribution so I hope you like guys!

I use ng-readonly with a condition to protect the input. Ng-repeat assigns a $index to each element iterated so I created a condition for ng-repeat to check if the $index of the element matchs with the $scope.eEditable variable. Then with ng-dblclick I can assign to $scope.eEditable the $index of the element clicked.

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
         <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}" ng-readonly='!($index == eEditable)' ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    $scope.eEditable= -1; //-1 by default. It doesn't match any $index from ng-repeat
```

One line in controller and two directives in the view, simple and it works

Comment: a very neat solution! probably we could call the variable $scope.editingIndex? Or maybe $scope.editingIndexArray if we want to support multiple lines of editing? But duplication still gives you more flexibility and separations, which are sometimes good to have.

Comment: Surely a limitation! I got to this solution because my problem didn't allow multiple edition. For multiple line edition keeping a clean model we would need to complicate the controller... In that case your solution would be cleaner

Comment: You can make it even shorter without creating a variable in the $scope. Attach a property to the item:

 <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}" ng-readonly="!item.readonly" ng-dblclick="item.readonly = !item.readonly"/