# editable table cell using angularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Is there a way to show data inside `td` and allow user to edit it in a way that the change will take place in the sql (MySQL in my case) table?
im creating a table from database using angularJS:

Creating The json file from the table:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from `user script settings`");
//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user id'];
    $row_array['script_id'] = $row['script id'];
    $row_array['cron_format'] = $row['cron format'];
    $row_array['schedule_last_update'] = $row['schedule last update'];
    $row_array['next_execution_time'] = $row['next execution time'];
    $row_array['script_exec'] = $row['script_exec'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

showing it in the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <td>user name</td>
        <td>script name</td>
        <td>cron format</td>
        <td>schedule last update</td>
        <td>next execution time</td>
        <td>script exec</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
            <td>{{x.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.script_id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.cron_format}}</td>
            <td>{{x.schedule_last_update}}</td>
            <td>{{x.next_execution_time}}</td>
            <td>{{x.script_exec}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function customersController($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("getData.php")//test3.php return a json file of users table
                .success(function(response) {$scope.data = response;});
    }
</script>
```

I want to allow user to change the cron format value and to update the table ...is there "angularish" way to due that?? if not i'll appreciate guidance for a php solution, thx!

Comment: Check something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794575/how-to-make-a-double-click-editable-table-in-angularjs-way On the `doneEditing` method on the example, you update your sql table.