# Only double-clicking can make an item editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make a list of items, double-clicking on one item makes it editable. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31403812/702977) and wrote the following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jurobijodo/6/edit?html,output)).

In the beginning, all the items are read-only; double-clicking on one item does make it editable. However, after having edited it, I realize that it is NOT read-only anymore. I think the right logic would be `once we have modified one item, it becomes read-only once again, only double-clicking could change it`.

Does anyone know how to amend the code to achieve this?

```js
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
  name: "item #1"
  }, {
  name: "item #2"
  }, {
  name: "item #3"
  }];
  $scope.eEditable = -1;
  }])
```

```css
  input {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
  <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}  {{$index}}" ng-readonly='$index !== eEditable' ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  {{count}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ng-blur='eEditable = -1'` to the `input`:

```
<input type="text" value="{{item.name}} {{$index}}" ng-blur='eEditable = -1' ng-readonly='$index !== eEditable' ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index" />
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wododipene/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: It works, thank you... Do you have any idea about my optional question?

Comment: I don't see any validation in the current code? Maybe you can do it in a `function` in your `controller` using `ng-enter`directive (this is not a standard directive, you can google for it).